# Which brand 1.4 Teleconverter ensures autofocus for Sigma 150-600mm C other than TC 1401 sigmas own

Tags: teleconverter

I have a Kenko tokina 1.4 teleconverter. When attached to 150-600mm C sigma lens and camera switched on, it shows Err01. However if the electrical contacts of the teleconverter are blocked with a tape the lens and teleconverter operates Manual. The same teleconverter works allright with a canon 70-200mm L lens with autofocus options. Tried all techniques to overcome Err01 error. Did not succeed. So which brand of 1.4 teleconverter offers autofocus.

Comment: What camera are you using?

Comment: How old is the TC? Kenko sometimes updates the firmware included in their TCs when it is necessary for them to work with newer Canon lenses/bodies. But the older ones already sold don't get the benefit of it, only the ones manufactured going forward. If you just bought a Kenko TC and it is an older one that does not work on your camera, some dealers will swap it out for a newer one if they know what that even means.

Comment: There are also several different models (4 element, 7 element, etc.) of Kenko 1.4X TCs for Canon EF mount. Which one do you have? Specifically, what is printed on the barrel of the TC?

Comment: It is the 4 element model. ie 1.4X Teleplus MC4. Obviously the old model. The camera body is canon 77D. Everything said, how come my 70-200mm Canon L lens when attached with the same TC works fine on this body(with autofocus)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: the one that the camera company makes.

For example, a Canon TC is guaranteed to work with Canon bodies and appropriate Canon lenses.

But, once you go to third party (Kenko, Sigma, etc) lenses or TC's, the guarantee is gone. The specifics of why this is get into the electronics and technology baked into the lens, TC, and camera - but the end result is that you should only ever expect a lens or TC to work with a body if the manufacturer says it will. (For example, if Kenko says their TC works with 60D and 70D and 70-200L, but they're missing the 80D or Sigma lenses on their approved list...then you have no evidence that their TC will work with either that body or lens).

TLDR; there is no list of autofocus approved TC's. There is only the TC, and it's approved camera body and lens combinations. If you go outside of those rec's - you're in uncharted territory. Things may still work, but don't be surprised if they don't.

Comment: Best practice when mixing third party TCs and lenses is to try it all (camera, TC, lens) together in the store *before* you buy. Bring your camera and TC and try it with the new lens, or bring your TC and lens and try it with the new camera, etc. Or buy from a seller that will take no-questions-asked returns for 15-30 days and test it at home as soon as you receive it.